# Is my VPN breaking my SSH or is something else going on? [raspberry pi, NOOBs]

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, vnc, raspberry-pi

My goal is to set up my Raspberry Pi such that it is always connected to my VPN and can be always accessed by SSH and VNC.

I use PrivateInternetAccess and Open VPN. Using [this article](http://dotslashnotes.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/how-to-run-a-command-automatically-at-system-boot-in-raspberry-pi-linux/comment-page-1/#comment-78) I figured out how to launch the VPN on boot (so that i can eventually ditch the monitor and operate entirely over SSH). Except now my SSH gives me:

> ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.146 port 22: Connection refused

According to the `ifconfig` output and my router settings, `192.168.1.146` is the right number, but it's not working at all. I can kill the VPN and the SSH is fine. I feel like I must be doing something wrong.

Edit: here's my IP table as asked by a commenter:

Before VPN:

> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ip route
>   default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
>   192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.143
>   192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.146

After VPN:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.194.36.5 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
10.194.36.1 via 10.194.36.5 dev tun0 
10.194.36.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.194.36.6 
85.159.237.4 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.194.36.5 dev tun0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.143 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.146
```

Comment: Can you post your routing table before and after you connect to the VPN? Use the `route` or `ip route` commands to get the table.

Comment: Is the computer that you are using to connect with behind a VPN?

Comment: @Logern no the computer I'm using to initiate the ssh connection is not behind a VPN. But it is on the same local network

Comment: @Bert sure no problem. (edit: will edit my original Q)

Comment: That error reads to me like a firewall issue.

Comment: @Davidw but how to fix? Is there a way to allow SSH through the firewall?

Comment: I'm not an expert on Linux firewalls, but take a look at iptables.

Comment: You might also look at the /etc/sshd.conf file, and see if something was changed there.